# AIRFLOW: How to set dependency on several task runs

Tags: python-3.x, etl, airflow

I am setting up a DAG which consists, to simplify, of three main tasks:

```
Extraction(today)     >> Fitting(today)
Extraction(yesterday) >> Fitting(today)

Fitting(yesterday)    >> Eval(today)
Extraction(today)     >> Eval(today)
```

So I want to feed today's model with today's and yesterday's data extraction, and want to evaluate yesterday's model against today's data extraction.

I could write each one of these as different tasks, but I want to avoid running yesterday's data extraction if it that was already done yesterday. Same for model fitting, so I would like to refer, in a DAG to a task with a different `execution_date` than that of the current DAG. Passing `execution_date` as a parameter doesn't seem to be a solution, and actually results in a

```
Broken DAG: [/var/lib/airflow/dags/test_dag.py] Dependency <Task(DummyOperator): fitting>, extraction already registered
```

because airflow thinks I'm assigning the same `extraction` task twice as a dependency to the `fit` task.

This is my code:

```
fit = DummyOperator(task_id='fitting',
                    depends_on_past=True,
                    dag=dag)

fit >> dag

fit.set_upstream([DummyOperator(task_id='extraction',
                                depends_on_past=False,
                                dag=dag,
                                execution_date=datetime(2018, 5, 18)
                                ),
                  DummyOperator(task_id='extraction',
                                depends_on_past=False,
                                dag=dag,
                                execution_date=datetime(2018, 5, 17)
                                )
                  ])
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the `task_id` should be unique and you have used the same `task_id='extraction'` twice.

You can have the code like below:

```
fit = DummyOperator(task_id='fitting',
                    dag=dag)

extract_yday = DummyOperator(task_id='extract_yday',
                             dag=dag)

extract_today = DummyOperator(task_id='extract_today',
                              dag=dag)

extract_yday >> fit
extract_today >> fit
```

Additionally you can also use [Airflow Macros](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#default-variables) for today's and yesterday's date: `{{ ds }}` and `{{ yesterday_ds }}` to pass it into your operators.